# ZOO Cache extremely big - 170 GB and growing!

Tags: cache, zoo

I have set up a site for a customer.

The site uses both Zoo and Widgetkit, many products, services and news pages have some Widgetkit slideshow in them.

There are "quite a few" pages and images....but I recently discovered that the folder cache\com_zoo\images has grown up to over 170 Gigabytes, with over 1 MILLION files in it and it's growing.

I don't think it's a normal behaviour, the "normal" weight of the site should be about 6 GB, including all images but mostly many PDFs, and software downloads that make up the total size.

Joomla cache is not enabled, so where can I disable Zoo/widgetkit cache as well? or whatever mihght be causing this issue in your opinion???

Comment: I believe Widgetkit auto caches it assets. You can delete the cache from the Joomla backend

Comment: it's ano option I have been considering, but I am afraid of doing it and to "clean" all images....however this doesn't seem to be normal behaviour to me...

Comment: I would suggest contacting Yootheme as they may be able to give better insight. You're right though, 170gb of cache seems unbelievably odd

Comment: if I go to joomla-->clean cache widgetkit show only 16 files for a measy 790 Kb...

Comment: Ok so it's quite possible that the files in this directory aren't actually cache files. You say it's 170gb...but what sort of files are they? Any videos in there?

Comment: all jpgs and png . nearly 1,8 million files now

thay all have the same name, plus an ID and dimensions...something like

01-my-image-107890-200x140
01-my-image-1112235-200x140
01-my-image-7777555-200x140

And so on...

Comment: see a partial view of the folder: http://s33.postimg.org/ca43of8sv/zoo_cache.png

Comment: I Discovered that any time I refresh the page a new copy of the image is generated th that folder....

Comment: Hmm, have you ensured you're using the latest version of Zoo and Widgetkit? It could be a bug.

Comment: widgetkit is the lastest...Zoo is 3.3.15 (latest is 3.3.17)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it was an issue with ZooLanders ImagePro component, it was not updated and the site has been migrated from Joomla 2.5 to 3.x

Upgrading Zoolanders Framework did the trick

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with Zoo that everybody is complaining about. I think Zoo expects you to use Joomla cache, but you aren't, so it is regenerating the images on every refresh. Zoo's official answer to this problem that it cannot be fixed. However, it can be fixed, but that requires modifying a core Zoo file (which most people do not like to do).

For backup reasons, I suggest you wipe out that folder (the images are being re-created anyway). If you don't, then you will reach a point where you don't have any space on your server. Additionally, if you run into an issue and you want to revert to a previous backup, then most likely your backup will fail.

I also suggest you develop a cron that deletes the contents of this cache folder daily.

Comment: is there a way to modify the interval that the zoo cache updates?  I am fine with hacking it.  Thanks!

Comment: Hello! I'm sure there is - but we've never modified it for any of our clients - so I can't really give an answer based on previous experience, and I don't have the luxury of researching it (and, in all fairness, I don't really like this extension).